# Enviar Parametros a un archivo exe (Ejecutable) c#

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un aplicativo web y de escritorio en c# para mis alumnos de primaria, de modo que ellos puedan loguearse en la web y luego descargar el programa para sus clases. Tanto la web como el aplicativo se encontraran en Azure Storage. El aplicativo de escritorio descargado necesitará las credenciales de la web.

El aplicativo que he creado es muy pequeño ya que solo se encarga de descargar y ejecutar las dll necesarias donde estarán los formularios con las clases y exámenes.

El problema que tengo es que deseo que los datos del login (usuario y/o contraseña) se envíen como parametros en el aplicativo de modo que no tengan que loguearse de nuevo en el aplicativo de escritorio.

He intentado que el aplicativo lea de alguna manera las cookies, pero descarte esta idea debido a que depende mucho del navegador.

La otra idea y mas comprensible es crear un servicio web que genere el archivo ejecutable(exe) en memoria (tiene que ser en memoria debido a que no tengo acceso de escritura y lectura en disco, estoy usando Azure Storage y Azure Service) y se descargue usando filestream o algo parecido.

He encontrado este ejemplo pero esto necesariamente necesita un directorio para generar el archivo exe, es posible generar el archivo exe en memoria?

O si es posible pasar parámetros a un archivo exe compilado.

```
Public Sub generateFile()

    Dim codeProvider As New VBCodeProvider()
    Dim icc As ICodeCompiler = codeProvider.CreateCompiler
    Dim Output As String = "C:\Program Files\MyApp.exe"


    Dim parameters As New CompilerParameters()
    Dim results As CompilerResults

    'Make sure we generate an EXE, not a DLL
    parameters.GenerateExecutable = True
    parameters.OutputAssembly = Output
    parameters.CompilerOptions = ("/target:winexe" & " " & "/win32icon:" & """") & "C:\Program Files\MyIcons\Icon.ico" & """"

    results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, txtCode.Text)

    If results.Errors.Count > 0 Then
        'There were compiler errors   
        Dim CompErr As CompilerError
        For Each CompErr In results.Errors
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Line number " & CompErr.Line &
                ", Error Number: " & CompErr.ErrorNumber &
                ", '" & CompErr.ErrorText & ";" &
                Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine)
        Next
    Else

        'Successfull Compile
        MessageBox.Show("Your file is successfully generated!", "Success")
    End If

End Sub
```

El aplicativo de escritorio es pequeño ,este solo se encarga de descargar y ejecutar las ultimas dll contenidas desde un directorio en azure storage, las clases y los formularios estarán en estas dll.

Muchas gracias por leer.

Comment: Hola.. me parece que estas complicando esto mucho.. que impide que el usuario la primera vez se loguee, y vos solo guardes esa info en un archivo de texto (por decir algo) y luego si ese archivo existe cuando abre el programa leas la info de ahi?

Comment: Como voy a guardar datos de las credenciales en un archivo de texto ???.. quiero que todo sea transparente para mis alumnos , ademas esta aplicación la usara todo el colegio.

Comment: Pero vos como vas a usar esas credenciales? o sea, como es el proceso de login? y tranquilamente podrias guardar igual que como hace el navegador con las cookies.. las aplicaciones de escritorio tambien pueden encriptar y hacer lo mismo que las web..

Comment: El ejemplo que estas mostrando compila un proyecto. Eso implica que el usuario tiene que tener, el codigo fuente, y tambien un compilador. Es muy probable que los usuarios no tengan esa. Tu idea de generar un "exe" en memoria (que no, no se puede) era para guardar las credenciales dentro del sistema?

Comment: No me entiendes, primero el alumno se loguea en la web, al dar click en instalar descargará un instalador,  puedo enviar esas credenciales al servidor pero como hago para que cuando descargue el instalador lleve consigo esas credenciales y ya no necesite autenticarse dos veces.

Comment: El ejemplo que estoy poniendo allí es para replicarlo en un servicio web , este que genere el aplicativo exe y retorne la descarga.

Comment: Vos queres que no vuelva a loguearse al abrir la aplicacion en su escritorio? Eso no lo vi nunca.. tratar de leer las cookies desde afuera del navegador es algo que no se si se puede hacer. Y por mas que soy de los que facilitan las cosas al usuario, en este caso creo que lo mejor es que vuelva a loguearse al abrir la aplicacion, y ahi guardes las credenciales. Porfa, aclara en tu pregunta todo esto que estas aclarando en comentarios.

Comment: Pero la idea de generar el archivo es para meterle las credenciales adentro?

Comment: Pude leer las cookies de internet explorer y de chrome ... sin embargo si cambias un valor de las cookies en chrome a veces lee los datos anteriores y no los actuales

Comment: Si quiero crear un servicio que genere el aplicativo exe ... que en realidad son pocas lineas ... y allí meterle las credenciales

Comment: Y si. se podria hacer.. Tambien podes pasarle parametros a un exe (es mas, el codigo que tenes lo hace). No se si hay respuesta para toda tu pregunta. la pregunta, se puede generar un exe en memoria es no. El compilador genera sobre un archivo fisico. Despues, todo el resto, me parece que es complicar algo que es mas simple.. pero se puede hacer..

Comment: El problema es que el usuario descarga el aplicativo y cuando le de a instalar (ejecutar el archivo) no hay manera de pasar los parametros ...

Comment: Tampoco me gustaría que el alumno se logueara dos veces , ese es el detalle que no es aceptable en las practicas de mi colegio .

Comment: mmm.. me quedo con tu ulitmo pensamiento. y si cambia sus credenciales en la pagina, como sabe el programa que las cambio??? Entiendo el "no me gustaria que se logueara dos veces", pero tene en cuenta que si usa ese programa desde otra pc distinta al cual lo bajo, no tiene esas credenciales del navegador.. y si directamente las cambia, ya el exe no le anda..

Comment: He leido todos los comentarios y la idea es *interesante*, por llamarla de algún modo. Entiendo lo que deseas lograr, ya en su momento he visto algo parecido a lo que intentas hacer, pero con diferencias notables en la forma de mantener la sesión para la descarga y para el funcionamiento correcto del aplicativo. Se me ocurren algunas formas de lograr el cometido, pero tal como comenta @gbianchi, me parece que te estás enredando más de la cuenta. No pasa nada si un usuario al usar el aplicativo deba hacer login, de hecho por seguridad y privacidad debería ser así.

Comment: @MauricioContreras me asusta mas el tema de como mantener los cambios de clave..

Comment: Claro @gbianchi, es que me parece que la clave es monolítica, es decir, no se le permite al usuario cambiarla. Si por algún motivo hay un cambio, tendrá que volver a descargar el aplicativo. Los cambios sólo los maneja el administrador, en este caso. Ya he visto eso antes.

Comment: No importa si el aplicativo no da en otra maquina, el alumno solo cuenta con sus credenciales para loguearse en la web de colegio asi que lo de la seguridad es lo menos importante, solo se instala el programa por única vez en su computadora ... me han impedido que se loguee en el aplicativo de escritorio por temas de la dirección del colegio,  obligatoriamente se debe loguear solo una vez en la web.

Comment: Yo no puedo ayudarte entonces. Lo que te pido es que dejes bien en claro en la pregunta que estas preguntando. Si es como leer cookies, o si es como compilar en memoria (que no se puede).

Comment: Ademas solo se podra instalar en una maquina por cada usuario ,esto seria muy facil de validar tomando los datos de la PC como la cpu, placa madre ... etc etc ... si se descubre que el alumno ha instalado dos veces el aplicativo se le llamará la atención.